# Extracting text with no consecutive whitespaces

Tags: regex, replace

I have a sample input below and I would like to extract each individual column using regex but it cant work for multiple consecutive blank spaces. I've tried
"`([0-9])\s+([0-9])\s+([A-Za-z0-9- ]+)\s{2,}([A-Za-z0-9- ]+)\s+([A-Za-z0-9]+)`" and it should work for each row.

```
Output
Module    Ports Type                                   Model            Serial No.
--------- ----- ------------------------------------   ---------------  -----------
1         2     CCS-7354 Series Supervisor Module      7354-SPP         JD546546527
2         1     Standby supervisor                     Unknown          Unknown
3         28    28-port SFP+ 10GigE Linecard           7234S-PC         FGK10449938
```

For the first row of the input result, I should get:

- "1" for "Output Module".
- "2" for "Ports"
- "CCS-7354 Series Supervisor Module" for "Type".
- "7354-SPP" for Model.
- "JD546546527" for "Serial No."

I'm getting "`CCS-7354 Series Supervisor Module      7354-SPP`         " for the Type which is incorrect.

Comment: Why not just count the dashes on the 3rd line and then retrieve the columns using the counts? Then you only need to trim the white-space. Then you can validate each resulting string using a regex. Divide and conquer.

Comment: Or you can perform the following regex multiple times (using find): `(.+?)(?:\s{2,}|$)` for each line...

Comment: @tripleee " I would like to extract each individual column using regex " -- Why have you chosen a non-regex answer for the Duplicate?

Comment: Fairy nuff; I added another duplicate.

Comment: @Jojoleo has your question been answered?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the Type column match group `[A-Za-z0-9- ]+` uses a "greedy" match.

Instead you should change it to a "reluctant" match `[A-Za-z0-9- ]+?`

Likewise, the Model column match group after that should also be changed to a reluctant match instead of a greedy match, so that it won't preemptively eat up all its trailing spaces.

Here is the final regex -- `([0-9])\s+([0-9])\s+([A-Za-z0-9- ]+?)\s{2,}([A-Za-z0-9- ]+?)\s+([A-Za-z0-9]+)`

Test here: [link](https://regex101.com/r/87Nj60/1)

Of course there are other ways you could write the regex such that you wouldn't need to use a reluctant match syntax. For example  `((?:\S|\s\S)+)`

This matches non-space characters separated by at most one whitespace character.

And putting it all together, it would be: `([0-9])\s+([0-9])\s+((?:\S|\s\S)+)\s+((?:\S|\s\S)+)\s+((?:\S|\s\S)+)`

Writing it this way reduces the amount of potential backtracking and should thus result in a consistently fast regex, regardless of input (although with this simple input it appears to be marginally slower).